# Function doesn't return message when value is missing

Tags: function, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to check if there are certain words in a string. So far I created a function that stores in the table test if the word is present in the string, then the function prints a message if the word is in the string and other message otherwise.

Here's the MWE:

```
stg = "In this string the words sky, dog, frog can be found"

function highlight(str)
    local test = {str:find("sky"),str:find("car"),str:find("glass")}
    local start, fim
    for k, v in ipairs(test) do
        if v ~= nil then
            print("There's something")
        elseif v == nil then
            print("There's nothing")
        end
    end
end

highlight(stg)
```

The weird thing is: the function only recognize the first word that is being checking, that is, the word `sky`. If the `stg` string has none of the matching words, the function returns nothing. Not even the message `There's nothing`.

How to make the function check the if the words are present or missing in the string and print the messages correctly?

Comment: because  `test = {1,nil,nil}` , but `nil` is equivalent to erasing the element, i.e. it is as if removed from the table.

Comment: Ok, but if I have `stg = "In this string the words glass, dog, frog can be found"` the function can't find glass. Why? Shouldn't I have `test = {nil, nil, 1}`? If so, then the conditional would accuse that there's something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ipairs` iterator stops when it finds a `nil` value, yet `string.find` will sometimes return `nil`. This means that inside your loop, `v` can never be `nil`.

One solution is to put only the search strings into the table and call `string.find` inside the loop:

```
stg = "In this string the words sky, dog, frog can be found"

function highlight(str)
    local test = {"sky","car","glass"}
    for k, v in ipairs(test) do
        if str:find(v) then
            print("There's something")
        else
            print("There's nothing")
        end
    end
end

highlight(stg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `table.pack` and iterate by index.

```lua
--[[
-- For Lua 5.1 and LuaJIT
function table.pack(...)
    return { n = select("#", ...), ... }
end
--]]

stg = "In this string the words sky, dog, frog can be found"

function highlight(str)
    local test = table.pack((str:find("sky")),(str:find("car")),(str:find("glass")))
    for n = 1, test.n do
        local v = test[n]
        if v ~= nil then
            print("There's something")
        else
            print("There's nothing")
        end
    end
end

highlight(stg)
```

[Live example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zXlZwpnsSlCk55Xb)

Comment: If `string.find` gets a match, it will return 2 values. This might result in `test.n` being 1 more than it should be. Maybe put parentheses around that last call to truncate it to one value.